# Run .rb (Ruby) file on a Shell Script

Tags: ruby, shell

I created a shell script to automate some processes, something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
ruby RubyFile.rb
```

But when I run this script, I get this error:

> ruby(2882): Operation not permitted

Any one knows what the hell is this?

Comment: Might be a problem with user permissions.

Comment: What's that Ruby script doing, exactly? Fiddling with `chown` or similar?

Comment: Agree with Tom. Not answering your question, but if your sh script just calls a rb script, you may insert `#!/bin/env ruby` in rb's first line and call it directly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use this when I want want to run Ruby code "as executable".

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

And then [chmod](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) the script.

```
chmod +x script.rb
```

And run it

```
./script.rb
```

I suggest usage of **[env](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uenv.htm)** because running a command through `/usr/bin/env` has the benefit of looking for whatever the default version of the program is in your current environment.

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? Why not just

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

or wherever your ruby is?

Comment: For instance, I use rvm, and this file doesn't exist on my OS