# Execution of ruby file fails from within shell script

Tags: ruby, shell, terminal, sh

I'm trying to use a `.rb` file from within a shell script like so:

```
ruby file.rb "input data"
```

In `file.rb` (it's in the root of a rails app), it requires another file which is throwing an error when I try the chmod method.  Any suggestions?

Doing `ruby file.rb "input data"` outside of the `.sh` file works completely fine.

I've tried the answers here: [Run .rb (Ruby) file on a Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166656/run-rb-ruby-file-on-a-shell-script), and `chmod` and adding `#!/usr/bin/ruby` do not work.  Would be grateful for any suggestions.

I'm on a mac, ruby-2.1.4.

When I try to run it, I get:

> "/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing `ruby file.rb "input data"` with

`bundler exec ruby file.rb "input data"` ?

You should also check [bundle-exec manpage](http://bundler.io/v1.10/man/bundle-exec.1.html) for more information on how bundler will run your script.

Comment: Stops the first error, now getting: `> /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 93 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)` any suggestions?

Comment: Just reinstalled bundler (`sudo gem install bundler`), what an interesting solution, who would've thought.  Thanks!